# Finding attributes of a list with getattr

Tags: python, list, object, getattr, getattribute

I have 2 modules.

1. `runtest.py`, where main is defined and

   ```
   if name == "main":

       # general purpose library
       na = nalib.NALib()
       ...
       classnames = na.get_classnames(classes)
   ```

   Hence I'm getting all the classes preset in the module in 'classnames'
2. `libna.py`

   This is where  `NALib` class and `get_classnames(self, classes)` is defined.

Now to manipulate with `classes` further, I need to have attributes of `classnames` (present in `runtest.py`)

I checked with `getattr` syntax that we need object and name for the same. Hence I'm not sure what is the exact way to print out attributes of classnames using `getattr`?

Comment: I think some underscores and spaces are missing because I copied it directly from notepad. Sorry for that.. but the code is working except the getattr thing.

Comment: did you consider using inspect? it allows you to get all classes from module, and the all attributes of those classes and so on so forth take a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html

Comment: @user3012759 Yeah got it. I tried it with classname directly instead of object and found it working. variable = getattr(classname, variabletotest)